# How to add Icon and Tooltip in Echart Title?

Tags: echarts

Want to add icon with Tooltip, in Echarts. 
Need like below example. Thank you. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have given the answer to this question in JavaScript as well as Angular

[How to display the icons in tooltip echarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60161125/how-to-display-the-icons-in-tooltip-echarts)

We cannot add icon but we can definitely use svg path as done by me.
Please let me know if you need any assistance.