# How to display the icons in tooltip echarts

Tags: javascript, typescript, echarts

here's the code:

***list.component.html***

```
<ng-template #uploadIcon>
  <i nz-icon nzType="upload" nzTheme="outline"></i>
</ng-template>
```

***list.component.ts***

```
 @ViewChild('uploadIcon') uploadIcon: TemplateRef<any>;
lineChart() {

    const _this = this;
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis',
        axisPointer: {
          animation: false
        },
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.8)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#ccc',
        padding: 10,
        textStyle: {
          color: '#000'
        },
        extraCssText: 'width: 250px',
        formatter: function (param: any) {
          let res = param[0].name + '<br/>';
          for (let x = 0; x < param.length; x++) {
            res += _this.uploadIcon + ' ' + param[x].seriesName + ': ' + Math.abs(param[x].data) + ' Mbit/s<br/>';
          }
        }
}

}
```

what I want to do here is to display the icon in the tooltip.
but I'm getting on the output. [object Object]
[enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeshE.png)

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for this ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-echarts-jc8d8c?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I am facing some issues with ngZone icons, so i have done it using standard anular material icons. I am adding my code.

Answer (score 1):

- First method you can use svg path directly inside the formatter function of tooltip. Dont forget to add css in styles.css. It will definitely work.

```js
tooltip: {
  trigger: "axis",
  axisPointer: {
    type: "cross",
    label: {
      backgroundColor: "#6a7985"
    }
  },
  formatter: function(param: any) {
    let res = param[0].name + "<br/>";

    for (let x = 0; x < param.length; x++) {
      res += `<svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
       <path d="M15.475,6.692l-4.084-4.083C11.32,2.538,11.223,2.5,11.125,2.5h-6c-0.413,0-0.75,0.337-0.75,0.75v13.5c0,0.412,0.337,0.75,0.75,0.75h9.75c0.412,0,0.75-0.338,0.75-0.75V6.94C15.609,6.839,15.554,6.771,15.475,6.692 M11.5,3.779l2.843,2.846H11.5V3.779z M14.875,16.75h-9.75V3.25h5.625V7c0,0.206,0.168,0.375,0.375,0.375h3.75V16.75z"></path>
      </svg>` + ' ' + param[x].seriesName + ': ' + Math.abs(param[x].data) + '<br/>'
    }
    return res;
  }
},
```

```css
/* Add this css into styles.css */

.svg-icon {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.svg-icon path,
.svg-icon polygon,
.svg-icon rect {
  fill: #fff;
}

.svg-icon circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

- second is you can using image tags right inside the formatter function, you can check if it works or not. for example:

```js
tooltip: {
  trigger: "axis",
  axisPointer: {
    type: "cross",
    label: {
      backgroundColor: "#6a7985"
    }
  },
  formatter: function(param: any) {
    let res = param[0].name + "<br/>";

    for (let x = 0; x < param.length; x++) {
      res += `<img src="your image source here" />` + ' ' + param[x].seriesName + ': ' + Math.abs(param[x].data) + '<br/>'
    }
    return res;
  }
},
```

Please let me know if it helps you.

Comment: there's an error on your code when I'm running the code.

Comment: can you create on stackblitz?

Comment: Seems like above method will not work. I am updating my code with 2 stratergies.

Comment: Please use this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n9my2h

Comment: how did you resize the icon, cause when I applying it on my project its to big

Comment: I have written in the solution as well, dont forget to add css to styles.css

Comment: The second solution works great. In order to style, you can pass inline css style into it like this "<img style="width: 40px; height: 30px;" src='image-source' />"